# Combining integer vectors

Tags: algorithm

I have a vector of length k where each element is a 2-by-m matrix that is a mapping between indices.  All elements are integers from the set {1,2,...,mn}, there are no duplicates within a given 2-by-m matrix, and I know what m and n are. I want an efficient way of finding n-1 of these 2-by-m matrices such that combining these mappings gives me all of the elements in {1,2,...,mn}. To make things more concrete, assume that m=n=3 and my vector is

4 3 6
2 7 5

4 6 3
1 9 8

9 1 8
6 2 7

7 8 3
2 1 4

I want the algorithm to output

4 3 6
2 7 5
1 8 9

which is found by combining the first two mappings.

Comment: do you have any bounds for n and m?

Comment: I have no bounds on k, but m and n will never be larger than 50.